# BLE challenge response smartphone authentication

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to build a simple challenge response protocol in order to authenticate a user to an Arduino via the smartphone (Android and iOS) using BLE. I'm having problems seeing how this would be implemented with BLE. What I want to do:

1. Arduino sends/broadcasts a challenge
2. Smartphone receives challenge and computes response
3. Smarpthone sends response to Arduino

The way I thought about implementing this is to have the Arduino (peripheral and server) start advertising when a button is pressed. Ideally an event would be triggered on the smartphone (central and client) when a certain service shows up. Then the smartphone connects to Arduino, reads the challenge characteristic and writes the response to it. Is this a good approach?

It appears though that it is not possible to trigger an event when a BLE service appears and I would continuously need to scan with the smartphone which is very battery intensive. Not sure how to get around this? Geofencing is not really an option since it can be inside. Maybe detecting if the user is walking, biking, standing still? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated =).

Comment: Have you read the core Bluetooth programming guide background mode section from Apple?  It describes the scenario where, once you have discovered a peripheral, you can issue a "connect" operation. If the peripheral isn't currently visible then the connect will complete at a later time when the peripheral becomes visible. I assume Android will have something similar

Comment: OP, it seems no one understood your question. Did you ever implement a BLE challenge and response protocol? I have the exact same need, I want a BLE central to issue a challenge to a peripheral upon connection. The peripheral should compute a response then write that back to the central. The central should then verify the response is valid before continuing. Maybe a simple shared key would work, but not sure how easy it would be to decompile the iOS app and discover the shared key.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS BLE connectivity looks like this:

- initialize CBluetoothManager,
- start discovering devices through bluetooth.
- when found particular peripheral that u're intrested in, connect to it via core manager and store this peripheral variable in ur Class,
- then.. u should STOP discovering cuz it's terrible for batteries ;) (as u said),
- after device's found, you can search through ***services***, ***characteristic*** and at the end through ***descriptors*** <-- **IN THIS ORDER** otherwise u won't get any of these,

ofc, from now on you're able to store each of these vars in your Class and work with them as you wish to. BLE on iOS's based on delegates and it's own lifecycle, each time when there will be something to read the event will trigger. When you will want to send some msg to Arduino back it shouldn't be a problem. In the partial answer for your question about

> 'when a certain service shows up. THEN the smarphone connects to
>   Arduino.'

you have to make steps ABOVE in order to read services. Hope that helps.